# Is there a way to get Select result from SQL Server 2008 with VB.Net without count?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to develop a tool to automatically update a database from a certain version to another where I have to run a bunch of scripts.

I can get the tool to run the script and can get the results from it. Now I'm trying to get the "Messages" window. I'm testing with simple scripts with selects only.

If I run the following query I get, the "Invalid object name 'tableDoesNotExist'." error

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableDoesNotExist
```

But if I run a working query I can't get the "(1 row(s) affected)" message

Here is the code I'm testing

```vb
Private Sub Execute_Query(ByVal fileInfo As BScript, X As SqlClient.SqlConnection)
    Dim objRead As New StreamReader(fileInfo.path)
    Dim commandobj As New SqlCommand()

    commandobj.CommandText = objRead.ReadToEnd()
    commandobj.Connection = X

    AddHandler X.InfoMessage, New SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(AddressOf InfoMessageHandler)
    Try
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(commandobj.ExecuteScalar()))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is there any property in the `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteNonQuery` that I can get the affected rows for select queries?

**I CAN'T CHANGE THE SCRIPTS**

Edit: As pointed out by [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) this could be a duplicate, but I'm already using a Handler and the string is empty

Here is the MessageHandler Sub

```vb
Private Sub InfoMessageHandler(sender As Object, e As SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)
    stringBuilder.Append(e.Message).AppendLine()
End Sub
```

And I'm declaring the stringBuilder as a global variable like this

```vb
Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder
```

The result is an empty string when running this

```vb
MessageBox.Show("String Builder: " & stringBuilder.ToString)
```

So I don't have any way to just get the "Messages" text?

Edit 2:
As a quick fix I'm using the following code

```
While reader.Read()
   rowCount = rowCount + 1
End While
```

But I would still like to know if it is possible to get the actual "Messages" text

Comment: If you can't update the scripts that would allow using like `@@ROWCOUNT` then maybe you can spin up a dataset and count the rows there? I assume this isn't working because the ROWCOUNT is OFF in the script.

Comment: Use `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteScalar()` and then `RecordsAffected` property. [SqlDataReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If you want a rowcount for a `SELECT * FROM...` query  you shouldn't be using `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`.  That's only ever going to return a single column of a single row.  Use `ExecuteReader()` instead and fill a datatable then you can use the Rows.Count to get a rowcount.

Comment: But ExecuteReader().RecordsAffected returns -1 for SELECT

Comment: @AimForNuts, it's my bad, I missed that you have SELECT queries only.

Comment: @GSerg I'll update the question.
I have that but I'm not getting anything from the string